# Credentials - Microsoft reporting library

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have problem with Microsoft.Reporting library. I need to access SQL reporting services and I have report name, address of the server and username and password. First of all I need to get all parameters needed for one specific report.

Here is my implementation so far :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<DataSourceCredentials> CredentialsEnumerable()
        {
            var credentials = new DataSourceCredentials
            {
                Name = @"domain\account",
                Password = @"password"
            };
            yield return credentials;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var credentials = new DataSourceCredentials
            {
                Name = @"domain\account",
                Password = @"password"
            };

            var report = new ReportViewer
            {
                ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
            };
            report.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/Archiv/Daily sales";
            report.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://serverIPaddress/reportserver");
            report.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(credentials);
            foreach (var param in report.ServerReport.GetParameters())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(param.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But I have problem with my code and mainly with :

```
report.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(credentials);
```

I am getting error, that it´s not possible to transfer from Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DataSourceCredentials to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
I have already tryid to use variable "credentials" and created IEnumerable class but it´s not working.

Can you please suggest what is wrong with my code? How to fix it and provide credentials for reporting server? Without credentials I am getting error "Not authorized"

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are passing a single element to SetDataSourceCredentials. It expects to receive an Array. Did you try with             _report.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(Program.CredentialsEnumerable());_ or simply with _report.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new DataSourceCredentials[] { credentials});_

Comment: Yes I tryed, not working. I can connect using webbrowser, but my program is still giving error "HTTP 401:Unauthorized"

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - wrong credentials parameter. 
Instead of :

```
report.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(credentials);
```

I used

```
report.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = credentials;
```

And it´s working !